# iOS 8 UIActivity: disable specific third-party sharers?

Tags: ios, ios8, pinterest, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I'm fighting with UIActivityViewController in iOS 8.  I'd built a custom Pinterest sharing mechanism which works beautifully in iOS 7 -- specifically, it uploads an image to my server, and then creates a Pin with that image and a URL which I specify.  This is the desired functionality.

Now, in iOS 8, Pinterest has implemented its own sharer, which accepts *either* a URL *or* an image.  If a URL is included in the list of Activity Items, the sharer pops up and asks the user which image s/he wants to share from the page at that URL, and totally ignores the image which is also in the list of Activity Items.  If there's no URL, and just the image, then the uploaded pin doesn't include a URL.

In order to resolve this, I need to do one of these things:

1. Disallow Pinterest's sharer from appearing in the list, so my customized sharer can show up instead;
2. Somehow specify a Source URL within a pin of an image using Pinterest's sharer (I doubt this is possible);
3. Remove all the other images from the generated web page.  I'd really rather not do this.

Or if all else fails, it would be useful to at least be able to detect *if* the user has Pinterest's sharer selected to show up in their list.

Does anyone know if there's a way to achieve any of these things?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, you could set a custom UIActivitySource on your UIActivityViewController.

Then check the incoming activity type for Pinterest. Then disable that via the exclusions.

Comment: I've added @"pinterest.ShareExtension" in the activitytype to exclude but that doesn't seem to be working.